# Angular 2 application 404 error when refresh from browser

Tags: angular2-routing

I just checked a site developed in angular 2 (https://thepoolcover.co.uk/), When i hard refresh this application internal pages its display appropriate page and related content but in my angular 2 app when i hard refresh any internal pages it shows 404 error. Can you please share the suggestions it would be great help for me

Comment: Helping you is impossible without providing your code. Please take a look on this [guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: use the hash location strategy: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles

Comment: is there any way by which we can implement this without hash location strategy. please look at the following application (https://thepoolcover.co.uk/) developed in angular 2 and working fine without using hash location strategy